# Suddenly website stopped to appear at Google Search

Tags: google-search, google-index, bing

We have a working website for more than a year. Everything was ok, site worked, appeared in the relevant Google searches etc.

Now, one day we discover that the site **totally** removed from Google Search results.
(I don't complain that it's low, not that). It just never appears, even if I search Google for the site name itself, it does not shows.

The site  subscribed to Google Webmaster Tools, Google Analytics and AdWords (currently no Ad campaigns are running). All these tools show no single warning. We received no complain email or anything.

I don't quite understand what could be the reason or is it a bug in a Google (?!)

Bing does not show the website either, but we never checked bing before.

Site does appear on Yahoo Search. On `ask.com` it does not appear.

Any clue would be helpful.

*One thing that I can think of - we are a dynamic DNS provider and we give to our users, domains like `user.website.com`. It is possible that some user may use that domain for some malicious activity, like sending spam or running a malware website or anything else.
I know that some antivirus (I think avira), probably because of the aforementioned reason, marks our website as a malware site.*

The site in question is `https://www.net-me.net`.

Comment: Maybe it's really too narrow, but maybe such situation may happen to someone else too....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google banned your website only because that users may use your domain for malicious activity. Google don't like those activity and so that only your website last ranking. Otherwise Google may banned you by Penguin 2.0 update. This update targets mainly on the websites that follows link farming techniques and having bad and spamming inbound links. If your website contains irrelevant or spamming porn website backlinks then it would be the reason.

**How to Get back your website?**

1. Check all your backlinks using Google Webmaster Tools of your website (Go to GWM click 'Traffic' again click 'Links to your site')
2. If you find any bad backlinks, request those website owners to remove your links or otherwise disavow those links using Google Disavow Tool.
3. Finally request Google to reconsider your website using Google Reconsideration Form

If you do these steps there may be more possible for your website to get back in Google results.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things noticed:

- When I try to load `http://www.net-me.net/` (non secure) in my browser, Avast Anti Virus is blocking it from loading, saying there is an infection. You can view the result [here](http://www.avast.com/lp-fr-virus-alert?p_ext=&utm_campaign=Virus_alert&utm_source=prg_fav_80_0&utm_medium=prg_systray&utm_content=./fa/en-ww/virus-alert-default&p_vir=URL%3aMal&p_prc=C%3a%5CProgram%20Files%5CGoogle%5CChrome%5CApplication%5Cchrome.exe&p_obj=http://www.net-me.net/&p_var=./fa/en-ww/virus-alert-default&p_pro=0&p_vep=8&p_ves=0&p_lqa=0&p_lsu=24&p_lst=0&p_lex=323&p_lng=en&p_lid=en-ww&p_elm=7&p_vbd=1489).
- When putting `https://www.net-me.net/` into this [header checker](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php), it says it is a 404 error. However I can browse it with my browser and crawl it with web crawling tools.

I'd say there are some serious issues here. You need to find out if your site is infected and why it is sometimes sending a 404 header status when certain user agents are trying to view, it maybe sending a 404 when Google and Bing web crawlers try to access the site.

Also do you have any messages in your Bing Webmaster Tools account?

Comment: As for header checking, when I try it, it gives "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request =>", and it seems to be the problem with the checker itself and not the website

Comment: We don't have an account at Bing Webmaster Tools.

Comment: The site is not infected. (I'm pretty sure, we use very responsible security measures).

Comment: Well there is something triggering Avast Anti virus when loading the site.

Comment: We contacted Avast and awaiting their answer for why it's blocked

Comment: header checker you mention, does not understand https: (try any https website, for example https://launchpad.net/). for HTTP://www.net-me.net/ , it returns the righ header (301 Moved Permanently etc.)

Comment: Avast told us that they are fixing it, and it will be unblocked in the next VPS update.